# What is "tap training" in snakes?

Tags: training, snakes, animal-handling

In [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-keeping-a-snake/5550#5550) I saw reference to "tap training" when handling snakes.

What is it, and do I need to learn it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tap training is a technique for condition training a snake,
designed and shown to improve your safety when handling it.

The precise method can vary, but in essence it always consists of giving the snake a particular signal
to indicate that you are about to handle it.
Some people recommend using a hook to lift it, some recommend stroking the snake gently with a hook,
while others simply tap the snake's home in a particular way before opening the door.

Whichever you do, the principle is the same: 
to train the animal such that it learns that the next thing which happens is neither food nor a threat. It creates a variation of the [conditioned response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) which [Ivan Pavlov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov) famously showed in dogs.