# Can I help a pet snake through the molting process?

Tags: snakes, molting

My friend's pet snake is starting to molt and since this is (the owner's) first experience through a molting, he is concerned.

We know to apply some humidity to help, but are there other techniques that would aid the process, or other things we should be concerned with?

While I see utility in "[My leopard gecko sometimes has trouble shedding. How can I help?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/my-leopard-gecko-sometimes-has-trouble-shedding-how-can-i-help)", geckos and snakes are dissimilar enough (snakes don't have limbs to help themselves shed; geckos and snakes have different diets - what's going on with my molting snake not eating, does he need food?) that the gecko answer is not necessarily sufficient for a snake molting question.

Comment: In addition to the humidity, providing a rough rock for it to rub again can help. That tip might be a good candidate for adding to http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-keeping-a-snake/5550#5550

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the snake skin doesn't come off in one piece, it probably has a problem shedding it's skin and it's a trip to the Vet. Of course there could be other reason's too. There is also something to help it with but not handling it.

> "Take care of your pet snake. Once you have recognized the shedding
> signs, it’s time to look at caring for your pet. Due to the snake will
> be more defensive, it might be wise to avoid handling it until the
> shedding process is complete. To hurry the process along, providing
> the snake with rough surfaces can help such as rocks and driftwood
> which should, of course, be cleaned. Your snake will also need
> humidity so make sure that the snake has a shallow dish of water in
> order to soak itself and the skin, allowing it to come off easily."
> From: http://www.wikihow.com/Care-for-a-Shedding-Snake
>
> Shedding Problems: If your snake does not completely shed its skin (an incomplete shed, also called dysecdysis ), it can signal health problems or problems with husbandry (e.g. humidity levels). Retained eye caps (where the eye caps are not shed along with the skin) may occur with an incomplete shed, but may also occur even if the rest of the skin was shed intact. For help with either of these problems, see the following links:
> Shedding Problems in Reptiles: http://exoticpets.about.com/od/reptilehealth/qt/sheddingproblem.htm

Retained Eye Caps in Snakes: http://exoticpets.about.com/od/snakes/qt/snakessheyecaps.htm